# Password Not Saving

Tags: ios, passwords, uialertcontroller

I have read through the questions here but cannot find out where I am going wrong.

I know KeyChain is better but just for my purposes I want to store it in NSUserDefaults.

When I try to save the password and reenter it, it doesn't work and continues to the ELSE. What line am I missing here?

```
#import "PasswordViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"




@interface PasswordViewController ()

@end

@implementation PasswordViewController



\

-(void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    [super viewDidAppear: animated];




       if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"AlreadyRan"] )
       {

           UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                         alertControllerWithTitle:@"Password"
                                         message:@"Set Your Password"
                                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

           UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                          //Do Some action here

                                                      }];
           UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                              [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                          }];

           [alert addAction:ok];
           [alert addAction:cancel];


           [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
               textField.placeholder = @"Password";
               textField.secureTextEntry = YES;

          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textField.text forKey:@"Password"];

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];



           }];

           [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

           [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"AlreadyRan"];

       }
}

- (IBAction)enterPassword {
    NSString * _password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Password"];
   NSLog(@"passField = %@ | _password = %@", passwordField.text, _password);
    if ([passwordField.text isEqual:_password]) {
        //Password is Correct
        NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
        UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotoView"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

    }


    else {
        //Password is wrong
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];

}
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(nonnull NSDictionary *)info {

    image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [ImageView setImage:image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];



}
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (IBAction)enterPassword:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSUserDefault` keys are case sensitive

You save with `@"Password"`

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:textField.text forKey:@"Password"];
```

Then  you retrieve with `@"password"`

```
NSString * _password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"password"];
```

In addition to that issue, you never used `_password` variable, so use it:

```
if ([passwordField.text isEqualToString:_password) {...}
```

And yes you are right , keychain is the appropriate place to save password not  `NSUserDefault`

---

EDIT:

save:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textField.text forKey:@"Password"];
```

Retrieve:

```
NSString * _password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Password"];
```

---

**TESTED & WORKING:**

**You must save the password in the ok completion handler**

```
-(void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    [super viewDidAppear: animated];
    
    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"AlreadyRan3"] )
    {
        
        UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"Password"
                                      message:@"Set Your Password"
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        
        
        
        UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                       NSString *password = alert.textFields[0].text;
                                                       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:password forKey:@"Password"];
                                                       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                                                       NSLog(@"NSUserDefaults %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
                                                       
                                                   }];
        UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                           [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                       }];
        [alert addAction:ok];
        [alert addAction:cancel];
        
        
        [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
            textField.placeholder = @"Password";
            textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
        }];
        
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"AlreadyRan"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Did as you suggested, the password added in the passwordField is always incorrect, always executes the else statement. I updated the code up top.

Comment: @BARIIIIIIICODE debug it please `NSLog(@"passField = %@ | _password = %@", passwordField.text, _password)`

Comment: passField = 55555555 | _password =  password is coming up blank

Comment: returns an error "No Visible @interface for NSUserDefaults declares selector setObjectForKey"

Comment: Still not working m8. The NSLog is still showing the same thing as well, want more of the code to see if the issue lies elsewhere. The scene is small I posted the rest of the code up top.

Comment: I think I have it....sort of....it doesn't execute the if statement but now the log is stating this: passField = 1234 | _password = <NSUserDefaults: 0x7fe153c0a980>

Comment: @BARIIIIIIICODE try this way `if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"AlreadyRan"] == nil )` but you need to learn to debug, add a breakpoint then you step through your code

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, rather new to this but thanks for getting it almost there. Not really sure how to debug guess thats nothing google can't handle.

Comment: no your not bothering me , Im here to answer questions, so ` == nil` did not help?

Comment: I assume you mean the if statement at the top, and no for some reason it keeps executing the else statement even though i know I am typing in my super secret password 1234 in correctly

Comment: @BARIIIIIIICODE see my update its working, you should save the password in the ok completion handler

Comment: Consider using constants and ALSO use a prefix like com.domainname.password to avoid any future collisions - https://davidquail.com/2012/01/15/simplified-nsuserdefaults/

Comment: @meda I am not home to try it but I appreciate all the time and effort you used to help me. I appreciate it. And will read though the links Stuart thank you

Comment: I tested the code and its fine, let me know how you make out